# Remove a Web Application from IIS 6.0 using Powershell

Tags: asp.net, iis, powershell

I am using Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6.0. I have written code for Adding a  Web Application to IIS using the following powershell code snippet.

```
# Get parameters passed to the script
param($appName, $appPath)
$path = [ADSI]"IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/ROOT"
$app = $path.Create("IIsWebVirtualDir", $appName)
$app.AppCreate3(1,"TestAppPool", $false)
$app.Put("AppFriendlyName", $appName)
$app.Put("Path", $appPath)
$app.put("EnableDirBrowsing", $true)
$app.SetInfo()
```

Now my requirement is Removing the Web Application from IIS.
I have tried using the commands AppDelete and AppDeleteRecursive. Both of them did not work. They are just deleting the application, but the folder shortcut still remains in IIS.

I have tried this code piece:

```
$path = [ADSI]"IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/ROOT/SampleService"
$app = $path.AppDelete()
```

Comment: Is it a physical or virtual directory you want to delete?

Comment: Virtual Directory in IIS. I have tried using the commands AppDelete and AppUnload neither or them worked.

Comment: What is your current code for deleting the application?

Comment: Added the code in Question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have resolved the issue using this code piece.

```
$path = [ADSI]"IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/ROOT"
$path.Delete("IIsWebVirtualDir","SampleService")
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you run this?

```
$path = [ADSI]"IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1/ROOT"

try {
  $vdir = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($path + "/SampleService")
  $vdir.AppDelete()
}
catch [Exception] {
  write-warning "Couldn't delete app: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}
```

Comment: The Application is removed, but the virtual directory in IIS remains. (i.e) I have the virtual Directory in IIS and if i right click on it, i get the option to Convert it to Web Application.

Comment: That sounds correct to me - does the directory physically exist on the system at the site root?

Comment: Yes. The Directory Exists. :)

Comment: So it is no longer a virtual directory - that bit has worked. You have successfully deleted the application. You can't delete the physical directory with this method, you'd need to use `remove-item` to remove the directory from the file system.

Comment: But i am seeing the application in the form of directory shortcut in IIS. Is there a way to remove it.

Comment: arco444.. Thanks for your support. Your suggestion worked fine in IIS 7. Please see my answer below for it to work on IIS 6.